# How to get the list of Security Groups a user belongs to using angualrjs

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, html

In my ASP.Net MVC SPA which is built using angular js I would like to show or hide a link based on whether a user is in a particular security group or not. I am planning to use ng-if directive in the html page to show or hide .

In my earlier project which is pure MVC.net application I had below method which gets me this list of security groups.

But how do I do it in the angularjs application ? Currently my application is on cloud and it authenticates user against the Azure Active Directory.

```
   internal static IEnumerable<string> GetSecurityGroups()
    {
        try
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = null;
            claimsPrincipal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;
            claimsPrincipal = ((claimsPrincipal == null) && (HttpContext.Current.User != null))
                ? HttpContext.Current.User as ClaimsPrincipal
                : claimsPrincipal;
            if (claimsPrincipal != null)
            {
                return ((ClaimsIdentity)claimsPrincipal.Identity).Claims
                    .Where(
                        claim =>
                            "group".Equals(claim.Type.Replace("http://sts.tmft.net/user/", ""),
                                StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    .Select(c => c.Value).ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Log.Error(exception);
        }
        return new[] { "No rights" };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could expose the above (`GetSecurityGroups`) as a web service, then have angular use the resultant rights object to show / hide sections.

Note that you will still need to restrict access to the functionality (i.e. the web service calls that the hidden sections expose) on the server side because you can't actually trust this kind of client side security to be anything more than a minor hurdle if there are users determined to use unauthorized functionality.